# Google Sheets want to delete all rows accept those that are in keep list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm not very good at this, but I have a google sheets doc, which has emails in the columns along with other columns of data.

Then I have another sheet with a list such as @hotmail.com @gmail.com and more

In the main sheet I want to remove all rows unless there is an (exception) above then keep that row.

I found this for excel but it's for keeping columns, but it kind of the thing I want...basically I want to only email to normal email addresses and remove all COMPANIES and other non SOCIAL contacts.

So for this, I want keep a list of social emails...and tell google sheets to remove all those rows that do not contain the "keep email" list.

```vb
Sub FOLSPrePaidRates()
    Dim keepColumn As Boolean
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    Dim columnHeading As String

    currentColumn = 1
    While currentColumn <= ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        columnHeading = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value

        'CHECK WHETHER TO KEEP THE COLUMN
        keepColumn = False
        If columnHeading = "Guest_Name" Then keepColumn = True
        If columnHeading = "BOOK_NUM" Then keepColumn = True
        If columnHeading = "arrival_Date" Then keepColumn = True
        If columnHeading = "Total_Amount" Then keepColumn = True
        If columnHeading = "Deposit_Paid" Then keepColumn = True
        If columnHeading = "Guaranty" Then keepColumn = True
        If columnHeading = "Rate" Then keepColumn = True


        If keepColumn Then
        'IF YES THEN SKIP TO THE NEXT COLUMN,
            currentColumn = currentColumn + 1
        Else
        'IF NO DELETE THE COLUMN
            ActiveSheet.Columns(currentColumn).Delete
        End If

        'LASTLY AN ESCAPE IN CASE THE SHEET HAS NO COLUMNS LEFT
        If (ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address = "$A$1") And (ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1").Text = "") Then Exit Sub
    Wend
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me please.

Sorry...I'm trying to create this mail merge auto thingy...and need help to remove all the wrong data.

thanks.

Comment: Google Apps Script is the language that you need to be using not Excel Scripting which I think is called Visual Basic for Applications.

Comment: You say that you want to hide rows, but the script you provide is hiding columns. If will be easier for the community to help you if you can provide a copy of your sheet (remove private information) which shows where the "keep email" criteria is located, and also please provide a more detailed description how your two sheets are related.

Comment: Please give sampel row you Will delete and sampel row you Will keep. And how Will you call the script?

Comment: Hello! I am unsure if I understood your request correctly but, do you want to remove all rows with emails that are not @ gmail.com, @ hotmail.com, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I just answer what I understand. You can use filters to get only an email list and then copy data and paste it in a new sheet:

[image]